# TypeError traceback, python 2.7

Tags: python, typeerror

I am new to coding, this is my script I run on python 2.7

```
binme=binascii.b2a_hex(url)
file=('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\n')
textfile = open(filename , 'w')
textfile.write(file.decode('base64')+binme+close)
```

But I get this error when I try to run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
  File "<module1>", line 32, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Please what is wrong?

Comment: What's that giant blob of binary data?

Comment: Please choose a title that reflects your programming question, and provide a simple example of what doesn't work so that we can run your code.

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Otherwise it is really hard to help you.

Comment: You do not have enough information to be able to find your problem.  Please give more information so we can help.

Comment: the script runs well from the beginning until it gets to: binme=binascii.b2a_hex(url)

Comment: `binme=binascii.b2a_hex(url)` fails on python 3 but "works" on 2.7. Its job is to turn a binary blob into a text representation. In python 3, binary and strings are quite a bit different. One usually doesn't  b2a a url, which already is a string.

Comment: The problem is that you are running this in python 3 but it is python 2 code. To verify, do `import sys;print(sys.version_info)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
textfile = open(filename , 'w')
textfile.write(bytes(file.decode('base64')+binme+close, 'UTF-8'))
```

or like this:

```
textfile = open(filename , 'wt') # note the 'wt' for write text
textfile.write(file.decode('base64')+binme+close)
```

Comment: This isn't the problem. OP hits the error before running this bit.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal verifiable example demonstrates the code at the point of failure in a way that is easily runnable by others. Since you have a version problem, I added an extra print of the version number.

```
import sys
import binascii
print(sys.version_info)
url='http://example.com/nowhere'
binme=binascii.b2a_hex(url)
```

Running this with python 2 and 3 I get

```
~/tmp $ python2 b.py
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

~/tmp $ python3 b.py
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=4, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 5, in <module>
    binme=binascii.b2a_hex(url)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

If you want the script to fail early on the wrong version, add this to the imports

```
import sys
assert sys.version_info[0] == 3, "Must run on python 3"
```